# How to make KDE3 visible for GDM?

Tags: gnome, kde, gdm

I have Gnome (default), KDE4 and KDE3 installed.

When I log out, GDM kicks in and I can select other desktop than Gnome -- among window managers, there is KDE4 (as KDE), but no KDE3.

**Question**: how to make KDE3 visible for GDM, so I could select it?

openSUSE 11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out even more general solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2920

it is described how to modify any session manager to "see" any session type. In my case it was sufficient to copy kde4.desktop to kde3.desktop and change the prefix path from /usr/ to /opt/kde3.

Answer (score 0):

Install kdebase3-session package.